# Table View Controller Cell Check Mark

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new at objective-c coding. I was trying to implement a check mark on a table view controller. I want check mark to seen when i click on a cell, and disappear when i re-click on that cell.

For example i found this code below. But i don't understand one thing clearly. What does "data" and "checkData" means ? Do we have to set them before that code ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do usual stuff here including getting the cell

    // determine the data from the IndexPath.row

    if (data == self.checkedData)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell; }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // determine the selected data from the IndexPath.row

    if (data != self.checkedData) {
       self.checkedData = data;
    }

    [tableView reloadData]; }
```

So I was searching for some codes and i couldn't find any code as i want.

I will be very happy for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did this sample code come from? Is it part of Apple's documentation?

Comment: No, from some other stackoverflow subject.

Comment: Tip: I would discourage you (and everyone) from using generic variable names like `data` and `checkedData`, unless the value truly is completely arbitrary data (which is uncommon). This sample code could definitely benefit from more meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is not good for general purposes. 
To support multiple cell selections, you need an extra data structure (e.g. an array of booleans or an `NSIndexSet`) to keep track of the selected indexes. And then, as soon as you get the `tableView:didSelectRowAtindexPath:` update the data structure and force the reload of the table, i.e. `[self.tableView reloadData]` in order to show/hide selection checkmarks

*Some chunks of code*

```
@implementation TableViewController {
    NSArray * _data;
    NSMutableIndexSet *_selectedIndexes;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    ...
    self.selectedIndexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    ...
    return self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if ([_selectedIndexes containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
            [_selectedIndexes removeIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
             [_selectedIndexes addIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        [tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....

    if ([_selectedIndexes containsIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    ...
    return cell; 
}
```

Note that `NSMutableIdexSet` must have the same length of `NSArray` representing the data structure you're using to populate tableView's cells.
Alternatively, as I said, you could use an array of BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that hold the selected index:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedIndex;
```

Then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            self.selectedIndex = -1;
      } else {
            self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
      }
      [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And present the checkmark:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // do usual stuff here including getting the cell

    if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can support a checkmark on a table cell. This example code seems to be assuming that you only have one checked cell in your table view, and tapping a different cell would move the checkmark to that other cell.

Basically, `checkedData` would be a property on your class (typically you would be using a subclass of `UITableViewController`, but it doesn't need to be, as long as your class conforms to both `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`). The `data` variable is derived from the selected row.

Here's one way you could fill in the gaps:

## YourClass.h

```
// ...
@property int checkedIndex;
// ...
```

## YourClass.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // do usual stuff here including getting the cell

    // See if this row is the checked row
    int thisRowIndex = indexPath.row;

    if (thisRowIndex == self.checkedIndex)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // determine the selected data from the IndexPath.row

    int thisRowIndex = indexPath.row;
    if (thisRowIndex != self.checkedData) {
        self.checkedIndex = thisRowIndex;
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

Of course, this doesn't really solve your problem. Since you want the cell to toggle, you will need to keep a record of which cells are on and which are off. If you're only toggling one or two cells, you could get away with having one or two `BOOL` properties on your class which represent the state of each cell. If you have a larger number of cells that you want to toggle, you should store the state of each cell in an `NSMutableArray`, and get/set the values that match up with each index.

## YourClass.h

```
// ...
{
    NSMutableArray *_checkedRows; // This is an instance variable, not a property.
}
// ...
```

## YourClass.m

```
// ================================================================
// Don't forget to initialize _checkedRows in your [init] method!!! 
// ================================================================

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // do usual stuff here including getting the cell

    // See if this row is the checked row
    BOOL rowIsChecked = [[_checkedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

    if (rowIsChecked)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // determine the selected data from the IndexPath.row

    // Set the state of the cell to the opposite of what it currently is.
    BOOL rowIsChecked = [[_checkedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    [_checkedRows replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row 
                            withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!rowIsChecked]];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```